# Find if Series Converges or Diverges Question.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

I was wondering if anyone knows what is the best test to use to find if this series converges or diverges.

$$\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{4k^5}{3^k+4k^3}$$

Edit: Sorry for the bad question, This was my first question on here. Also, I tried some tests, but wanted to know the best test to use for this specific problem.

Comment: The informal answer is that polynomials grow much slower than exponentials... the $3^k$ term is the only term here that matters so your sum behaves much like $\sum\frac{1}{3^k}$ which converges.  To see this more formally, for starters try a ratio test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of options: you can successfully apply the Root Test of the Ratio Test of the (Direct) Comparison Test or even the (generalized) Limit Comparison Test here. A key fact is that an exponential function grows faster than any power function, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^a}{b^n}=0 \quad \text{for any } a>0,b>1.$$

For example, when applying the Root Test, in the denominator you'll have $\sqrt[k]{3^k+4k^3}=3\sqrt[k]{1+\frac{4k^3}{3^k}}$, and then use this property that I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{4k^5}{3^k+4k^3} \le 
\sum^{∞}_{k=1} \frac{4k^5}{3^k}$$

The Ratio test on RHS verifies that it is convergent.

Comment: What is RHS? __

Comment: The right-hand side of the inequality.